# how to upload two field data using laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to upload two images with two category using two input file methods. i used this html tag to upload two different images.

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">QR Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile2">Cloud QR Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile2">
  </div>
</form>
```

i want to upload these two fields to same table. i used this function to upload one file.

```
if($request->hasFile('qr_image')){

            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('qr_image')->getClientOriginalName();

            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);

            $extension = $request->file('qr_image')->getClientOriginalExtension();

            $fileNameToStore = $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

            $path = $request->file('qr_image')->storeAs('public/image', $fileNameToStore);

        }
        else{
            $fileNameToStore = 'nofile.jpg';
        }
```

How to make this one to get two input file fields.

Comment: Add `<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">` and name your input fields and use those names in the controller.

Comment: i want to make my controller method for two different file names. i used this form enctype. it's not my problem. how to add two file names into hasFile

Comment: use another `hasfile ('second_file_name')` or use loop like `foreach (Input::file() as $key => $value) {`

Comment: What are your 2 file input names? You want to save image names as two entries or 2 fields of same row? What is your model and table structure?

Answer (score 0):

use enctype = "multipart/form-data" and method="post" attributes

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">QR Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile1">
  </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlFile2">Cloud QR Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="exampleFormControlFile2">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: i want to fix my controller. this form method is ok